# How to detect change inside jquery Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

I have a html table with rows.
Each row has a action column with a button and when pressing this button i want to show a input field in the second td which the user have to fill out and submit, first then the event/click is completed else the input should disappear again.

```
<table>
     <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>user-Input</th>
              <th>data3</th>
              <th>data4</th>
              <th>data5</th>
              <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="customers">
          <tr>
              <td>1</td><td></td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td><button type='button' class='acceptCustomerBut'>GO</button></td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

javascript/jquery

```
$(document).on("click", ".acceptCustomerBut", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().find("td:nth-child(2)").html("<input type='number' name='customer_id'>");
    // DO SOMETHING
});
```

DO SOMETHING - im thinking if its possible to make the function detect if the input has received values with jquery's .on("change") if not, hide the input field?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).on("click", ".acceptCustomerBut", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $td=$(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(1)");
    if($td.find('input').length){ // check input length, if exists then hide it
        $td.find('input').hide();
    } else { // else add it
        $td.html("<input type='number' name='customer_id'>");
    }
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/5KjvR/)

Comment: Ah i see. But how do i detect if the user puts values into the generated input field with jquerys .on("change"). if he does i have to call another function handling the data if not hide the input field again

Comment: Should i look at a trigger maybe?

Comment: You want to hide input, only if it has no value?

Comment: Oh, i think ive got it! :) ill update my question after. thank you.